# Android warning: Possible overdraw, root element paints

Tags: java, android, background-image

In my android app, I am getting the warning about the possible overdraw. I am trying to follow the thread here to fix it:

["Possible overdraw: Root element paints background "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994454/possible-overdraw-root-element-paints-background)

But If I try it, it makes all my layouts messed up, like the buttons are in different places and different looking, and if I open a dialog box, its width is really small...

I made a theme here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_normal</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then in manifest I have

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.activity.idsconnect.ActivityAdminMainMenu"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_activity_admin_main_menu" 
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
```

And then removed the background attribute from the root linear layout on the activity.

Am I doing something wrong here? Does anyone know?

Thanks.

Comment: try using `android:windowBackground` instead of `android:background` in your theme.

Comment: this works better, but my dialog boxes' width is still showing way too small.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this @omega? I'm having the same issue and the suggested fixes don't work for me.