# Possible overdraw: Root element paints background i can't resolve

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

hello i have this simple view:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@drawable/lavagna_verticale"
     android:orientation="vertical" > 
     
      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/voto_lavagna"
          android:layout_width="235sp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:textColor="@color/bianco"
          android:textSize="30sp"
          android:textStyle="bold"/>       
</RelativeLayout>
```

i can show an image into background all ok but with lint check:

```html
Possible overdraw: Root element paints background @drawable/lavagna_verticale with a 
 theme that also paints a background (inferred theme is @android:style/Theme.Holo)
```

i created a new style:

```html
    <style name="SfondoLavagnaVerticale" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/lavagna_verticale</item>
 </style>
```

and change my view:

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:theme="@style/SfondoLavagnaVerticale"
     android:orientation="vertical" > 
  ..
  ....
  .....
```

now i do not have error from lint but i can't show my image what i can do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace

```
android:theme="@style/SfondoLavagnaVerticale"
```

With

```
style="@style/SfondoLavagnaVerticale"
```

in your RelativeLayout

To resolve lint error. Jump here ["Possible overdraw: Root element paints background "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994454/possible-overdraw-root-element-paints-background)